# Cannot create a database at runtime

Tags: c#, sql-server

I wrote class by Microsoft samples but it doesn't work:

```
public class Database
{
    private bool Create()
    {
        string path = GetPath();
        Debug.WriteLine("Path: " + path);

        try
        {
            string connectionString = string.Format(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True");

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();


                DetachDatabase(DatabaseName);

                cmd.CommandText = string.Format("CREATE DATABASE {0} ON (NAME = N'{0}', FILENAME = '{1}')", DatabaseName, path);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            if (File.Exists(path)) return true;
            else return false;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    public static bool DetachDatabase(string dbName)
    {
        try
        {
            string connectionString = string.Format(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True");
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = string.Format("exec sp_detach_db '{0}'", dbName);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                return true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private string GetPath()
    {
        string filename = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
        return new Uri(Path.GetDirectoryName(filename)).LocalPath + "\\" + DatabaseName + DatabaseType;
    }
}
```

Acrashes with errors when it calls `connection.Open()`:

> Вызвано исключение: "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException" в
>   System.Data.dll Вызвано исключение:
>   "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException" в SK.exe "SK.vshost.exe" (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: SK.vshost.exe). Загружено
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Transactions.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_ru_b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.resources.dll".
>   Сборка модуля выполнена без символов. System.Transactions Critical: 0
>   : http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/UnhandledНеобработанное
>   исключениеSK.vshost.exeSystem.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,
>   System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089При
>   установлении соединения с SQL Server произошла ошибка, связанная с
>   сетью или с определенным экземпляром. Сервер не найден или недоступен.
>   Убедитесь, что имя экземпляра указано правильно и что на SQL Server
>   разрешены удаленные соединения. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces,
>   error: 50 - Произошла ошибка Local Database Runtime.Невозможно создать
>   автоматический экземпляр. Дополнительные сведения об ошибке см. в
>   журнале событий приложений Windows. )   в
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling)    в
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions)...

In Russian it says that `the server not found or not available`.

P.S. I retried few variants that I found but it doesn't work all same.

Comment: The exception explains what happened. Since it's in Russian though, only you can understand it. Seeing the work `Network` though suggests that you can't even connect to the server.

Comment: Search for the dozens of questions in SO that deal with `LocalDB` and how to connect to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Сервер не найден или недоступен. Убедитесь, что имя экземпляра указано
>   правильно и что на SQL Server разрешены удаленные соединения.

This means you can't connect to your sql server. Your connection string is wrong.

Comment: It's a LocalDB connection string. The correct connection string depends on the version of SQL Server Express installed - if it is installed

Comment: Yeah, I understood it. But I don't know how to write it correctly. I need to create a database without the installed MS SQL Server. Create a built-in database. Sorry, I never make it early.

Comment: Do I need to install the SQL Server Express? How can I build it in my app to the user doesn't need to install it?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Ok, it seems, I understood. Thank you! Правда, очень помогли, а то после MySQL как-то запутано все.